# I have a slight issue with my code and im not sure

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've just started learning python and wanted to make a discord bot hoping to learn some coding on the way. Right now im trying to make a chatbot and im facing an issue.

```py
from prsaw import RandomStuff
rs = RandomStuff(async_mode = True)
```

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user == message.author:
        return

    if message.channel.id == 833292700744548392:
        response = await rs.get_ai_response(message.content)
        await message.reply(response)

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Johaa\PycharmProjects\Kushina 2.0\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    rs = RandomStuff(async_mode = True)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'api_key'
```

I'm not sure how to get an 'api key' or what it is

***video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKfaobGpKlQ***

Comment: You need to pass a Random Stuff API key to the `RandomStuff` call.

Comment: @Makonede How do i get one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to pass api_key to RandomStuff. So instead of this:

```
rs = RandomStuff(async_mode = True)
```

Try this:

```
rs = RandomStuff(async_mode = True, api_key = api_key)
```

[Here's how to get an api key.](https://api-docs.pgamerx.com/guides/api-key) An API Key gives you access to use the API.

Comment: Thanks, by any chance do you know a way to make it stay things because right now it says "{'message': 'not found'}" and i have some intents like if someone says hi it replies with hello but don't know how to sort of import it over and make the bot use the replies.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it, but here's the documentation page, https://rapidapi.com/pgamerxdev/api/random-stuff-api/. Hope that helps.